# Limitations in Correlation Analysis

Tags: correlation

Suppose I have the following dataset that shows the faculty composition of different colleges and the total number of drop outs that happened in an academic year.

Here is some R code for this problem:

```
set.seed(123) 
n <- 100
college_id <- paste0("college_", 1:n)
percent_engineering <- runif(n, 0, 100)
percent_science <- runif(n, 0, 100 - percent_engineering)
percent_liberal_arts <- runif(n, 0, 100 - percent_engineering - percent_science)
percent_other <- 100 - percent_engineering - percent_science - percent_liberal_arts
number_of_dropouts <- sample(0:100, n, replace = TRUE)
number_of_students <- sample(200:1000, n, replace = TRUE)


df <- data.frame(college_id,
                 percent_engineering,
                 percent_science,
                 percent_liberal_arts,
                 percent_other,
                 number_of_dropouts, number_of_students)

df$drop_out_rate <- (df$number_of_dropouts/df$number_of_students)*100
```

I could be interested in trying to answer the following question: **Is it possible that when colleges tend to be more engineering based are more correlated with larger dropout rates in general?** (e.g. lets say I don't have access to the number of drop outs per faculty per college)

A very basic way to explore this question could be to calculate correlations between faculty compositions and drop out rates:

```
library(ggplot2)
plot_list <- list()
percent_cols <- c("percent_engineering", "percent_science", "percent_liberal_arts", "percent_other")

for (col in percent_cols) {
    # Calculate the Pearson and Spearman correlation coefficients
    pearson_cor <- cor(df[[col]], df$drop_out_rate, method = "pearson")
    spearman_cor <- cor(df[[col]], df$drop_out_rate, method = "spearman")
    
    # Create the scatter plot with a line of best fit
    p <- ggplot(df, aes_string(x = col, y = "drop_out_rate")) +
        geom_point() +
        geom_smooth(method = "lm") +
        labs(
            x = col,
            y = "Dropout Rate",
            title = paste("Relationship between", col, "and Dropout Rate"),
            subtitle = paste(
                "Pearson correlation =", round(pearson_cor, 2),
                "| Spearman correlation =", round(spearman_cor, 2)
            )
        )
    
    # Add the plot to the list
    plot_list[[col]] <- p
}

# Assign the plots to individual variables
g1 <- plot_list[["percent_engineering"]]
g2 <- plot_list[["percent_science"]]
g3 <- plot_list[["percent_liberal_arts"]]
g4 <- plot_list[["percent_other"]]

library(gridExtra)
grid.arrange(g1, g2, g3,g4 ,ncol = 2)
```

[image]

At first glance, this approach might be suitable to study correlations between total drop out rates and the composition of different faculties (e.g. engineering) - however, I think there might be some problems with this approach.

One of the first problems that comes to mind is that this approach is not taking into account the effect of other variables when calculating correlations. As a humorous example, perhaps Science Students and Engineering Students hate each other - and when a college has more than x% Science Students and y% Engineering Students, this results in fights and these fights result in drop outs. Thus, the patterns and trends that would be observed during this analysis between pairs of variables might not necessarily be only attributable to those pairs.

As such, I think it would be a better idea to fit a Regression Model to this data and then be able to find out the "average effect of each increase in faculty percent on drop out rate (adjusted over the other variables".

But as such, **what are the limitations of performing and making conclusions from this type of correlation analysis?**

Thanks!

Comment: Well, it still will be a correlational analysis. So, usual limitations still apply. Besides percent variables are functions of each other, and they add up to 100 (i.e., compositional data). So, you might have high collinearity for some them. In fact, if you include all percent variables, one would be dropped due to collinearity.

Answer (score 3):

I think you've identified the most likely culprit of misleading conclusions from looking at bivariate correlations: *[confounding](/questions/tagged/confounding)*

However, performing a regression would only adjust for known and measured confounders in the data.  If a variable is omitted and that variable is correlated with drop out and faculty, then the analysis remains biased.